# Set-SPSiteAdministration - remove secondary administrator

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, site-collection

Using PowerShell I can update a site collection secondary administrator (as farm administrator):

```
Set-SPSiteAdministration -Identity http://contoso/sites/test -OwnerAlias "domain\testuser"
```

This works fine. But how can I remove the secondary administrator using PowerShell? So reverse the above.

Answer (score 1):

For removing you can try this one.

```
Get-SPSite http://contoso/sites/test | Set-SPSite -SecondaryOwner $null
```

[Set-SPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Set-SPSite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Also Check this post : [SharePoint: Add/Remove Site Collection administrators with Powershell](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2013/10/sharepoint-addremove-site-collection.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Secondary owner is still showing in 'change site collection administrators'

Comment: did you try to second link?